# IntentService + SmsManager not getting onReceive call for registeredReceivers

Tags: android, service, sms

I have an IntentService used for sending Text messages to people Asynchronously via SmsManager. The problem I'm facing is with the service I register for delivering/sending receivers to listen for when either of those two actions complete. Here is my code:

```
public static final String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
private int mPartCounter;

public SendTextService(String name){
    super(name);
}

public SendTextService(){
    super(SendTextService.class.getSimpleName());
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mMessage = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_CONTENT);
    mNumbers = intent.getStringArrayExtra(MESSAGE_CONTACTS);
    registerReceivers();
    sendMessage();
}

private void sendMessage(String message, String number){
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> splitMessage = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
    mPartCounter = splitMessage.size();

    /* Handle multipart messages */
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sendIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliverIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    PendingIntent sendIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
    PendingIntent deliverIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);

    /* Add a PendingIntent for send/deliver for each part needed */
    for(int i=0; i<mPartCounter; ++i) {
        sendIntents.add(sendIntent);
        deliverIntents.add(deliverIntent);
    }

    /* Send the messages in either multi-parts or single */
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, sendIntent, deliverIntent);
}

private void registerReceivers(){
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sending failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));
}
```

I have set breakpoints and the code never gets here, but the messages are indeed sent?? Anyone see the problem?

Oh all, I start my service via my own receiver:

```
static public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent textService = new Intent(context, SendTextService.class);
        textService.putExtra(MESSAGE_CONTENT, intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_CONTENT));
        textService.putExtra(MESSAGE_CONTACTS, intent.getStringArrayExtra(MESSAGE_CONTACTS));
        context.startService(textService);
    }
}
```

and there are both defined in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".service.SendTextService"/>
<receiver android:name=".service.SendTextService$MessageReceiver"/>
```

This is how I call my receiver:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(SendActivity.this, SendTextService.MessageReceiver.class);
broadcastIntent.putExtra(SendTextService.MESSAGE_CONTACTS, mNumbers);
broadcastIntent.putExtra(SendTextService.MESSAGE_CONTENT, mBodyEdit.getText().toString());
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Logcat has this output, but it's because I am trying to unregister them when I see they are all sent... but that detection happens in the receivers for handling snet messages (which is why I have this question up):

```
    12-02 22:55:36.238 6268-6268/org.thorrism.masstexter E/ActivityThread: Service org.thorrism.masstexter.service.SendTextService has leaked IntentReceiver org.thorrism.masstexter.service.SendTextService$1@3397aff3 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
12-02 22:55:36.238 6268-6268/org.thorrism.masstexter E/ActivityThread: android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service org.thorrism.masstexter.service.SendTextService has leaked IntentReceiver org.thorrism.masstexter.service.SendTextService$1@3397aff3 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
12-02 22:55:36.238 6268-6268/org.thorrism.masstexter E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1009)
12-02 22:55:36.238 6268-6268/org.thorrism.masstexter E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:810)
12-02 22:55:36.238 6268-6268/org.thorrism.masstexter E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:2068)
12-02 22:55:36.238 6268-6268/org.thorrism.masstexter E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:2048)
12-02 22:55:36.238 6268-6268/org.thorrism.masstexter E/ActivityThread:     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:2042)
12-02 22:55:36.238 6268-6268/org.thorrism.masstexter E/ActivityThread:     at org.thorrism.masstexter.service.SendTextService.registerReceivers(SendTextService.java:135)
12-02 22:55:36.238 6268-6268/org.thorrism.masstexter E/ActivityThread:     at org.thorrism.masstexter.service.SendTextService.startSendMessages(SendTextService.java:66)
12-02 22:55:36.238 6268-6268/org.thorrism.masstexter E/ActivityThread:     at org.thorrism.masstexter.service.SendTextService.onHandleIntent(SendTextService.java:51)
```

Comment: permissions in manifest? any error in log cat?

Comment: you're too quick... yes permissions log cat does have something but not related.. I think

Comment: I have updated post with logcat output and permissions

Comment: @rosenthal: where calling `unregisterReceiver ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IntentService`s stop themselves pretty much as soon as the `onHandleIntent()` method ends. You're getting the log message about a leaked Receiver because you've not unregistered the Receiver before that happens, which you can't really do with your code as it is, since you're using an anonymous Receiver instance.

If you mean to register the Receiver dynamically, you need to do so in a component that will remain running until that broadcast is sent; e.g., in an `Activity` or a regular `Service`.

You can also statically register the Receiver in your manifest, as you've done with `MessageReceiver`, and it will be started when the broadcast fires, whether your `IntentService` is running or not, but you need to specify an `<intent-filter>` for it in the manifest if you use an implicit `Intent`. For example:

```
<receiver android:name=".service.SendTextService$SentReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="SMS_SENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Otherwise, you can use an explicit `Intent` - one that specifies the Receiver class - and omit the filter. This is probably the preferred method, as there's no chance that another app's Receiver will get the broadcast. If you have the Receiver statically registered in the manifest, you don't need to register it dynamically.

Also, you don't need to broadcast to a Receiver to start your `IntentService`. You can just directly start the Service with the necessary extras attached to its `Intent`. That is, your `MessageReceiver` isn't really necessary.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Your advice made perfect sense and I was able to do it. I also removed the Recieever but now I use one for communication with the Activity via the Service. I register the broadcast receiver dynamically when the activity resumes and unregister it when the activity pauses. The receiver  makes it so I know when all the messages have been sent because my service broadcasts to the receiver i registered in my activity via intent filter